# Matlab: Remove noisy peaks

Tags: fft, matlab

I have transformed an image with the help of method `fft2` now i want to locate the noisy peaks and erase them as shown in the following image link:

**[Image with Noisy Peaks](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/425/Lab5/Picts/noise_spectrum.png)**

Kindly suggest matlab functionality for achieving this

This is what i did so far

```
  F = fft2(myImage);

  F = fftshift(F); % Center FFT

  F = abs(F); % Get the magnitude
  F = log(F+1); % Use log, for perceptual scaling, and +1 since log(0) is undefined
  F = mat2gray(F); % Use mat2gray to scale the image between 0 and 1

  imshow(F,[]); % Display the result
```

Comment: i've get the fourier transform of the image, now i want to locate the noisy peaks other than origin and remove them

Comment: That image looks like a logo, not something with a bunch of noise. Is that really what you want to remove noise from?

Comment: No someone has edited it kindly follow the link "Image with Noisy peaks" , i want all noisy peeks to be removed at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a mask of that shows/represents points that exceed certain threshold and position. Let's create arrays of position.

```
[x y] = meshgrid(1:size(a, 2), 1:size(a, 1));  % x-y coordinate of the data
ft = 0.5;                                      % Try different values for your case.
mask = F > ft && y < 0.4*size(a, 1) && y > 0.6*size(a, 1);
F(mask) = 0;
```

You should be able to check `mask` to see if you have located the right positions. `imagesc(mask)` would be very helpful during your trial-and-error step. Note that I don't have `x` rules in the example but you could potentially add them if it could help to reduce the search space.